# How to perform the next rxjs request after?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have rxjs method that removes data:

```
return this.registryDataSource.deleteRegistry(registry.Id).pipe(()).subscribe();
```

How to call the next function `this.registryDataSource.getRegistry()` instantly after `deleteRegistry` in pipe? Call only if previous rxjs was successfull?

I have tried:

```
  return this.registryDataSource.deleteRegistry(registry.Id).pipe((concatMap() => this.registryDataSource.getRegistry())).subscribe();
```

I am not sure, should I use `concatMap()` or `mergeMap()` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
return this.registryDataSource.deleteRegistry(registry.Id)
   .pipe(
       switchMap(() => this.registryDataSource.getRegistry()
   ).subscribe(
       (getRegistryResoponse) => { //Two requests were successfull },
       (err) => { // Error in one of the requests. }
   )
```

If error occur in deleteRegistry request, the chain will jump to the error function in the subscribe and `this.registryDataSource.getRegistry()` won't be executed.

Comment: Why not concatMap() or mergeMap?

Comment: You can use them also, depending on your scenario.

Comment: ConcatMap will serve as a queue,
MergeMap will fire `getRegistry` for each `deleteRegistry` valid response and SwitchMap will unsubscribe for an ongoing `getRegistry` if you got a new `deleteRegistry`. Learn the specifics from here please: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-map-mergemap-switchmap-and-concatmap-833fc1fb09ff

Comment: Thank you, what if I need to call method that loads data after `switchMap(()`?

Comment: I guess this is async also right? Then add another switchMap to load it: `.pipe(switchMap(() => this.registryDataSource.getRegistry(), switchMap(() => this.registryDataSource.loadAllRegistries()
   )`

Comment: Thank you, why `switchMap` not in own pipe `this.registryDataSource.getRegistry().pipe()`? but outside?